# Run pytest in Google Build cloudbuild.yaml to determine if build passes or not

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, pytest, google-cloud-build

My project structure is as follows:

```
cloudbuild.yaml
requirements.txt
functions/
    folder_a/
        test/
            main_test.py
        main.py
```

My `cloudbuild.yaml`

```
steps:
# Install
- name: 'docker.io/library/python:3.7'
  args: ['pip', 'install', '-t', '/workspace/lib', '-r', 'requirements.txt']
# Test
- name: '?'
  args: ['pytest', 'functions/**/*_test.py']
```

What builder do I use to run pytest? I just installed it using the previous install step. Should I use that same docker image? How do I stop my build from passing until pytest successfully finishes all tests?

Answer (score 4):

Each step runs in a separate container, so you should do it all in one step:

```
steps:
# This step runs the unit tests on the app
- name: 'docker.io/library/python:3.7'
  id: Test
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
  args:
  - -c
  - 'pip install -t /workspace/lib -r requirements.txt && pytest functions/**/*_test.py'
```

See ["GitOps-style continuous delivery with Cloud Build"](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build) for more details.

Comment: Errors with `ERROR: build step 0 "python:3.7-slim" failed: exit status 127
... /bin/sh: 1: pytest: not found`

Comment: I changed `.. && pytest ...` to `.. && /lib/bin/pytest ...` and got the new error: `File "/workspace/lib/bin/pytest", line 6, in <module>
from pytest import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'`

Comment: Again changed to `$(which py.test) functions/**/test/*_test.py`, now errors `/bin/sh: 1: functions/folder_a/test/main_test.py: Permission denied`

Comment: Is pytest in your `requirements.txt` file? Seems like it's not getting installed.

Comment: Yes, doing an `ls -R` shows that it is installed correctly.

Comment: What are the file permissions on main_test.py?